# Making XAML layout dynamic

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I am new to using XAML and C# in general so this is probably an easy question but I have my XAML as so

```
<Page
x:Class="Tournament_Director_Windows.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Tournament_Director_Windows"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="LightGray">
    <Button  Style="{StaticResource AddAppBarButtonStyle}" Foreground="#FF094AB2" Click="onAddNewBowlerClick" HorizontalAlignment="Right" RenderTransformOrigin="0.4,0.508" Margin="0,10,115,679"/>
    <ListView Height="648" Width="377" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="itemListView" ItemClick="itemListView_ItemClick" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Margin="225,110,0,0">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Bowlers" Height="54" Width="177" FontSize="50" Foreground="#FF094AB2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="225,10,964,704"/>
    <Button  Style="{StaticResource RefreshAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="onSyncClick"  Background="#FFF8FCFD" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="#FF094AB2" BorderBrush="#FFFBF9F9" Margin="0,10,10,679"/>
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Width="220" Background="Silver" SelectionChanged="MenuListView_SelectionChanged">

        <!--<ListView.Resources> 
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF094AB2" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="75"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>-->

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF094AB2" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="75"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <x:String>Bowlers</x:String>
        <x:String>Brackets</x:String>
        <x:String>Scores</x:String>
    </ListView>
    <ScrollViewer Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="754" Margin="602,110,0,10">

    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

my question is about the `ScrollViewer` at the end, I have it as a set width but what I want to do is have the width fill the rest of the screen from its set position next to my `ListView` so no matter what screen size you have it looks the same and there is not a big space if you have a bigger screen or it gets cut off because the screen is smaller.

How can I do that?

Comment: I suppose the `Grid` also supports `Width="1*"` in WinRT, which is what you're after. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `<ColumnDefinitions>` with width property `"Auto"` or `"*"` and `<RowDefinitions>` with height property `"Auto"` or `"*"` for grid. In this case you can manage what part of your content has permanent size and what part will resize with a window.